# How to loop check_plain function into this array?

Tags: php

I'd like to combine this check_plain function with the following , but I'm not that familiar with PHP. These values are retrieved from the URL of a "Thank You" page a customer lands on after purchase, then echo'ed elsewhere on the page, but it's been brought to my attention this is a potential security issue, and hence checkplain was recommended.

```
<?
  function check_plain($text) {
  return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }
?>


<?php 
  $email=$_GET["email"];
  $itemdesc=$_GET["itemdesc"];
  $totalpaid=$_GET["totalpaid"];
  $bookingnum=$_GET["bookingnum"];
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=php+call+function+from+within+a+function) or the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php)? Learning how to do it will be far more helpful than asking someone to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this simple `function`

```
<?php

 function check_plain($text) {
  return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
  }
 $user_details = array_map('check_plain', $_GET);

$email=$user_details["email"];
$itemdesc=$user_details["itemdesc"];
$totalpaid=$user_details["totalpaid"];
$bookingnum=$user_details["bookingnum"];
```

?>

for more info about `array_map`.Please refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `check_plain` function to each element in `$_GET` array, like this:

```
$escapedGet = array_map('check_plain', $_GET);
```

and then use it like this:

```
$email = $escapedGet["email"];
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you want to call check_plain function on the values...

```
$email = check_plain($_GET["email"]);
$itemdesc = check_plain($_GET["itemdesc"]);
$totalpaid = check_plain($_GET["totalpaid"]);
$bookingnum = check_plain($_GET["bookingnum"]);
```